# IN, OUT, or INOUT not valid for parameter in procedure

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, rpg

I'm calling a RPG procedure from my java , and I'm getting the an error.

```
ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - [SQL0469] IN, OUT, or INOUT not valid for parameter 4 in procedure  in *N.
```

One of the parameters in  query is both IN and OUT.

I just tried to write a small query as below

```
 "CALL " + procedureName + "(2014, 1, 1.00, 0,'Y' )");
```

Here parameter number 4 (0)  is the output the query returns also as an input.

Any help?

This is the actual query I wrote

```
   rpgCall = connection.prepareCall("CALL " + procName + "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

            rpgCall .setInt(1, params.year);
            rpgCall .setInt(2, params.value1);
            rpgCall .setInt(3, params.value2);
            rpgCall .setInt(4,params.value3); 
            rpgCall .setString(5, "Y");
            rpgCall .execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the parameter is OUT then you need to have a variable in that position - you can't pass it a constant because the procedure cannot change that.

Comment: It should be like this   sqlCall.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.DECIMAL);   http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-out-parameter-example/